# Create native query using Activiti

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, activiti

Hi I'm working with activiti workflow.I want to get all tasks along with all the candidate user in a primefaces datatable. So I'm writing a native query to get these values but I'm having a null value on managementService. Do I need to implement this class?or is there a library I need to import? How should I proceed?

```
@Autowired
private static ManagementService managementService;

 public static List<Task> retrieveAllTasks(){
    ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();

    String taskTable = managementService.getTableName(TaskEntity.class);
    String identityLinkTable = managementService.getTableName(IdentityLinkEntity.class);

    List<Task> groupTasks = taskService.createNativeTaskQuery().sql("select _TASK.*" +
        "  from " + taskTable + " _TASK" +
        "  join " + identityLinkTable + " _LINK on _TASK.ID_ = _LINK.TASK_ID_" +
        " where _LINK.TYPE_ = 'candidate'").list();

return groupTasks;
```

Comment: Why do you retrieving the ManagementService via Autowiring, when you get the TaskService via the default process engine (TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();) ? You could retrieve the ManagementService in the same way. Please show us your Spring configuration - also autowiring static fields looks strange...

Comment: Thanks. It works. ManagementService managementService = processEngine.getManagementService();

Comment: I'm having another issue.. I write this sql to get the task id and user id. Apparently this sql statement is not returning the user id. it returns only the task id and task name from the table Task. I execute this sql in sqldeveloper, and I get all values from table task and table Identity Link. Do you know why I don't get the values of the table identity Link in groupTasks?

Comment: With custom queries, you could only query the fields of the entity itself - in your case only fields of Task, because the ibatis mapping is used to map the query result to the fields of the Task implementation. I think you have to setup/implement an own ORM for your use case, for example with JPA and Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to work it out with hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

Autowiring doesn't work with static fields. Remove the static keyword and make sure, that the implementation of the interface is correctly detected as Spring bean.